# Can't figure out SSL with node and express (https)

Tags: node.js, express, ssl-certificate

I've been working at making a website, but after getting my website to work I set out to try and get SSL so the annoying "warning" symbol would go away. Unfortunately I've come to a real impasse and all the resources I've found to help me work through this seem to be outdated or at least not compatible with what I'm doing.

My original working server.js file:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
```

What I tried but ends up not working:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/certificate.crt'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('cert/ca_bundle.crt'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('cert/private.key')
};

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const httpsPort = process.env.PORT || 3030;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
httpsPort.createServer(options, app).listen(httpsPort);
```

I am struggling to wrap my head around the entire venture since I've started on this https issue.
Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `httpsPort.createServer` -> throws error, since `httpsPort` is integer. And why your SSL requests different port? Do you actually have setup for `http://example.com:3000` _AND_ `https://example.com3030`?

Comment: I had setup a forward to it (The same way I had the original working on port 3000), but I don't even know if I'm *allowed* to do that, just that I didn't get any issues when doing it on namecheap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, there are a few issues here. First you try to `listen` on two different things. `app.listen` is a short version of `http.createServer({ ...options }, app)`.

Second - your code is `httpsPort.createServer(options, app).listen(httpsPort);`, which basically translates to `3030.createServer(options, app).listen(3030)`. Here's what I usually do:

```js
const https = require('https');
const server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port)
```

If you would like to support both, then you need to include both `http` and `https` packages, and have an if-else (or something similar) so that you use the proper package to create the server.

You should **not** listen on the app in this scenario!

Comment: I've tried doing what you outlined (And changing app.listen(port); -> server.listen(port);), but unfortunately I'm still not seeing my page get served. I think I'm not understanding fully, when you say not to listen on the app, am I supposed to do something other than what I tried?